# MyQuery incorrectly identifies array as instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a jQuery like pattern for a library, and started with [this blog post](http://blog.buymeasoda.com/creating-a-jquery-like-chaining-api/) as a base...

```
var myQuery, $$;

(function() {

    myQuery = $$ = function(selector) {
        return new MyQuery(selector);
    };

    var MyQuery = function(selector) {
        // Lets make a really simplistic selector implementation for demo purposes
        var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            this[i] = nodes[i];
        }
        this.length = nodes.length;
        return this;
    };

    // Expose the prototype object via myQuery.fn so methods can be added later
    myQuery.fn = MyQuery.prototype = {
        // API Methods
        hide: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                this[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            return this;
        },
        remove: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                this[i].parentNode.removeChild(this[i]);
            }
            return this;
        }
        // More methods here, each using 'return this', to enable chaining
    };

}());
```

I am having trouble with the specifics of the prototype chain.

jQuery (v2.1.1) works as expected, correctly identifying only instances, and not arrays as `instanceof` it's constructor...

```
var jq = $();
// undefined
jq instanceof $.fn.constructor
// true
[] instanceof $.fn.constructor
// false
```

MyQuery identifies instances, but also incorrectly identifies arrays as an instance of it's constructor...

```
var mq = $$();
// undefined
mq instanceof $$.fn.constructor
// true
[] instanceof $$.fn.constructor
//true
```

What is missing from MyQuery in order for it to correctly identify instances, without false positives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting `$$.fn.constructor` to anything in particular, therefore it is the generic `Object` constructor.

And `[]` is an instanceof `Object` so:

```
[] instanceof $$.fn.constructor`
```

is essentially the same as:

```
[] instanceof Object
```

which reports `true` as expected.

---

If you add this line to the end of your IIFE:

```
myQuery.fn.constructor = MyQuery;
```

you will then get the same results as JQuery.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n1of58n4/